# element rectangle

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to copy from the screen the position of a `PictureBox`. My code looks like this:

Form1.cs:

```
_recorder = new ScreenRecord();
_recorder.StartRecording(
   pictureBox1,
   pictureBox1.RectangleToScreen(new Rectangle())
);
```

ScreenRecord.cs:

```
class ScreenRecord
{
   private ScreenBitmap scBitmap;

   public void StartRecording(PictureBox cam, Rectangle rect)
   {
      scBitmap = new ScreenBitmap(cam, rect);
      cam.Image = scBitmap.GetBitmap();
   }
}
```

ScreenBitmap.cs:

```
class ScreenBitmap
{
   private PictureBox camBox;
   private Rectangle camLocation;

   public ScreenBitmap(PictureBox cam, Rectangle rect)
   {
      camBox = cam;
      camLocation = rect;
   }

   public Bitmap GetBitmap()
   {
      Bitmap screenBitmap = GetScreen();
      return screenBitmap;
   }

   private Bitmap GetScreen()
   {
      Bitmap scBitmap = new Bitmap(camBox.Width, camBox.Height);
      Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(scBitmap);

      g.CopyFromScreen(
         camLocation.X,
         camLocation.Y,
         0,
         0,
         new Size(camBox.Width, camBox.Height)
      );

      return scBitmap;
   }
}
```

I'm getting the `pictureBox1` rectangle and then copying from the screen, but it looks like its not working. If I try the following code:

```
g.CopyFromScreen(
   camLocation.X,
   121,
   0,
   0,
   new Size(camBox.Width, camBox.Height)
);
```

where `121` is a random number it works (I get an image, not the part I want, but it works) so the Y coordinate of the rectangle may be wrong? Or I'm missing something...

Comment: what exactly do you want to capture and show in the picturebox?

Comment: Show the part of the screen where the picturebox is

Comment: that means if for example picturebox image is an all green image you want to assign to the picturebox that same green image?...because you are copying the picturebox

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I want to get whats behind the form picturebox rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what is behind the `PictureBox`, with the opacity trick. The rest you can easily transfer to your code:

```
 //just when you are about to capture screen take opacity and later restore it.
 this.Opacity = 0.0;
 Point first = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);

 Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bit);

 g.CopyFromScreen(first.X,first.Y, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Size);
 this.Opacity = 1.0;
 pictureBox1.Image = bit;
```

You can test this code by creating a new WinForms project, add a `Button` and a `PictureBox`, and place this code in the `Button`'s `Click` event handler.

Comment: If I plan to use this on a while true loop will it be very cpu consuming?

Comment: i think it will be more on the amount of memory,since with each iteration you are creating a new bitmap.